# golang jsonrpc call java json rpc

Tags: java, go, rpc

I was trying to connect golang programs with java programs by json rpc, but ran into some trouble. I use the "net/rpc/jsonrpc" package from golang native packages, and "jsonrpc4j" for java. I use stream mode to create a server in java, because golang's jsonrpc just supports tcp invoke. But it still gets the error response in golang client:

> err: invalid error map[code:-32602 message:Invalid method parameters]

Meanwhile the java server is also encountering error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
>    at [Source: com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.NoCloseInputStream@385b5b5c; line: 1, column: 1]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3747)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3687)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2202)
>       at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcServer.handle(JsonRpcServer.java:224)
>       at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.StreamServer$Server.run(StreamServer.java:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

I don't understand why it does not work, is there any discipline that exists in the jsonrpc protocol that golang can't invoke java or do I just not do it right?

Comment: I was trying something similar earlier and ran into a dead end. To the best of my knowledge the Go rpc package only supports Go servers and clients, not those written in another language. Here is one ref on the Golang-Nuts google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/F0cuNKsH7c4

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a better answer. This is something that I was trying to make work earlier and couldn't get to happen. I've read that only Go clients can rpc to Go servers.

There are two means which I resorted to after trying to make json/rpc work between Java and Go, maybe you can tailor something similar to your needs.

In one case I used the net/http package and did a basic web server in Go and then used HandlerFunc to call functions/methods based on url requests. The requests were based on simple http form actions. I then redirected back to the main page as I wanted the "app" to stay in front of the user as I just needed the "/submit" url to trigger a method with the values passed in from the form.

Not all that elegant but it worked in a pinch to rapidly set up a way to gather information and it could be instantly "deployed" by letting my colleagues know what port I was listening on.

In the second case, since a friend of mine was programming the Java side I set up a socket a listed for a pattern of bytes that we had agreed on which would call a particular function.

Not so adaptable but if you what what you're getting  from the client it works out fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You solve the problem in a very clever way. But I had it worked out finally. There are 3 key points. Firstly, golang's json-rpc has obey the rules of its rpc, which the function should have only one income pramater. Secondly, the method name registered in java json-rpc is not like golang, it's just the name of the method, not including the class name. Thirdly,  keep programs communicate in socket, not Http. [Here is my demo code if you are intrested](http://www.cnblogs.com/geomantic/p/4751859.html), Sorry for write it in Chinese, you could just look through the code.